# Select rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, select, group-by, db2

I have a table from which I have to select some rows based on the following conditions.

1. If more than one row exists with same DocumentRef, then select all the rows if BlockNumber is empty for all rows
2. If more than one row exists with same DocumentRef, then select only 1 row (ordered by DocumentId asc) with BlockNumber IS NOT EMPTY
3. If only one row exists with DocumentRef, select it irrespective of anything

Table:
[image]

I was trying to group it by DocumentRef and filter with having but having can only have aggregate functions. I think I will have to provide multiple conditions in having separated by OR. Please give me some direction.

Comment: Can you please add a tag for a database you use ?

Comment: @VBoka I have updated the tags. Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Please post attempted SQL with issues so we can help. This appears to be course work and we would hate to impair your learning curve.

Comment: This is not course work. The actual table contains more columns and some sensitive data. I have created a dummy table for this problem with similar data. I am converting some business logic, written in Java, to SQL and this use case is one of the business rules. I will try to work on it again and see what can I achieve and will share with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when blocknumber is not null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by documentref) as num_bn_notnull,
             rank() over (partition by documentref
                          order by (case when blocknumber is not null then documentid end) desc nulls last
                         ) as rnk
      from t
     ) t
where num_bn_notnull = 0 or
      rnk = 1;
```

Or, you can use `exists` clauses:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.documentref = t.documentref and
                        t2.blocknumber is not null
                 ) or
       t.documentid = (select max(t2.documentid)
                       from t t2
                       where t2.documentref = t.documentref and
                             t2.blocknumber is not null
                      );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `(documentref, blocknumber, documentid)`.

Actually, by a quirk of the SQL language, I think this works as well:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.documentid >= any (select t2.documentid
                           from t t2
                           where t2.documentref = t.documentref and
                                 t2.blocknumber is not null
                           order by t2.documentid
                           fetch first 1 row only
                          );
```

The subquery returns an empty set if all `blocknumber`s are `NULL`.  By definition, any document id matches the condition on an empty set.

Comment: Your second solution works perfectly for me. In my case, the table in question is a derived table, so I created indexes on the underlying tables. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table to a query that returns for each `documentref` the maximum `documentid` for all the `blocknumber`s that are not `null` or `null` if they are all `null`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join (
  select 
    documentref,
    max(case when blocknumber is not null then documentid end) maxid 
  from tablename
  group by documentref
) d on d.documentref = t.documentref 
   and t.documentid = coalesce(d.maxid, t.documentid)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b24244d961c3ce8c9e3279734facbe19).
Results:

```
> DOCUMENTID | DOCUMENTREF | WARDID | BLOCKNUMBER
> ---------: | ----------: | -----: | ----------:
>  203962537 |   100000126 |      B |           A
>  203962538 |   100000130 |      B |           A
>  203962542 |   100000151 |   null |        null
>  203962543 |   100000151 |   null |        null
>  203962544 |   100000180 |      B |           A
>  203962546 |   100000181 |      B |           A
>  203962551 |   100000185 |   null |        null
>  203962552 |   100000186 |      B |           A
```

Comment: This is perfect!